# how to run libreoffice python script using scriptforge

Tags: python, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to organize my python project that currently only adds a menu to a libreoffice calc menu bar:

```
# this file is called AddMenu.py which is located in 'C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\share\Scripts\python'

def create_menu(args=None):
   o_doc = CreateScriptService("Document")
   o_menu = o_doc.CreateMenu("Test Menu")
   o_menu.AddItem("About", command="About")
   o_menu.AddItem("Testing",
                 script="vnd.sun.star.script:AddMenu.py$item_b_listener?language=Python&location=user")

def item_b_listener(args):
    bas = CreateScriptService("Basic")
    s_args = args.split(",")
    msg = f"Menu name: {s_args[0]}\n"
    msg += f"Menu item: {s_args[1]}\n"
    msg += f"Item ID: {s_args[2]}\n"
    msg += f"Item status: {s_args[3]}"
    bas.MsgBox(msg)
```

The menu and buttons are added as expected, and About works fine.  However, when I click on the "Test Menu" I get an error:

```
Library :   ScriptForge
Service :   Session
Method :    ExecutePythonScript
Arguments: [Scope], Script, arg0[, arg1] ...


A serious error has been detected in your code on argument : « Script ».

The requested Python script could not be located in the given libraries and modules.
« Scope » = user
« Script » = AddMenu.py$item_b_listener


THE EXECUTION IS CANCELLED.

Do you want to receive more information about the 'ExecutePythonScript' method ?
```

Any suggestions?

Follow up question: how do I run a python script when calc starts?  Since the menu doesn't persist on restarting calc, I need to run the macro to reinstall it

Comment: "Follow-up question" — That's correct, it should be posted as a separate question. You could fix this by removing the second part and posting it as a different question, along with a description of what you have researched or tried so far.

Comment: I've created another thread for this followup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75346270/add-menu-to-libreoffice-that-persists-app-restarts-via-a-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> &location=user

That indicates the LibreOffice user profile directory, for example `C:\Users\(your username)\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice\4\user\Scripts\python`.

So either change that part to `&location=application` or move the script to the user profile directory.

https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/sq/text/sbasic/python/python_locations.html

Comment: I changed the code to be &location=application, but that didn't work.  I moved the coded to the user profile directory you suggested and it works fine.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the script is unable to locate the `item_b_listener` function. The script that is trying to call the function `item_b_listener` is located in a different location than the definition of the function. To resolve this issue, you need to make sure that the script is able to locate the function.

One way to do this is to create a separate Python module (file) containing the `item_b_listener` function, and then import that module into `AddMenu.py`.

Regarding your follow-up question, you can run a python script when LibreOffice Calc starts by adding it to the Calc startup macro. To do this, follow these steps:

Go to the Tools menu and select `Macros > Organize Macros > Python.`
In the Python macro dialog, select your script and click on the `Edit` button.
In the Python macro editor, add the following code to the global section of the script:

```
def Main():
# your script code here
```

Save and close the macro editor.
In the Python macro dialog, click on the Run button to test your script.
To make sure your script runs every time Calc starts, go to `Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Advanced` and check the box for "Run macro from an autoexec section."
Save the options and restart Calc.
Now, your script should run every time Calc starts.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. item_b_listener is in the same file as create_menu (AddMenu.py). It should be being registered as a callback for clicking on the menu item "Testing" and called when I click on it.

Comment: I've moved this discussion to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75346270/add-menu-to-libreoffice-that-persists-app-restarts-via-a-script

Comment: "In the Python macro dialog, select your script and click on the Edit button" — What version and platform are you using? In all the versions I have used, including the new LibreOffice 7.5 on Windows, the Edit button is disabled. APSO offers a menu at `Tools > Macros > Organize python scripts`, but that is different from what is written in your answer. Also, under `Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Advanced`, there is no "Run macro from an autoexec section," nor do I see any mention of this from searching online.