# Add menu to libreoffice that persists app restarts via a script

Tags: python, libreoffice

I'd like to run one script once that adds a menu that persists through `LibreOffice` restarts.

I understand how to add a menu to `LibreOffice` [as posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75331489/how-to-run-libreoffice-python-script-using-scriptforge?noredirect=1#comment132933276_75331489) (but it disappears on app restart).

I see that it's possible to modify the start macro manually [as posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75331489/how-to-run-libreoffice-python-script-using-scriptforge?noredirect=1#comment132933276_75331489).

Is it possible to modify the start script and add it to the `autoexec` section via a single script?

I tried to add the menu manually (as in Tools > Macros > Customize) but my (latest 7.4.5.1 x64) version does not have a Customize section of the Macros menu.

[image: Customize is missing!]

I am feeling very foolish as I can't see where you are suggesting to add the start macro
[image: customize dialog]

I'm trying this code (which is supposed to add a popup to the startup), but the length of basic_libraries  is always zero:

```
import uno
from com.sun.star.beans import PropertyValue

print('here 1')
# Connect to LibreOffice
localContext = uno.getComponentContext()
print('here 1.1')
resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext)
print('here 1.2')
ctx = resolver.resolve("uno:socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext")
print('here 1.3')
smgr = ctx.ServiceManager
print('here 2')

# Open a new document
desktop = smgr.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", ctx)
doc = desktop.loadComponentFromURL("private:factory/scalc", "_blank", 0, ())

print('here 3')
# Add a start macro
macro_name = "Module1.start"
macro_code = "Sub Main\n    msgbox \"Hello World!\"\nEnd Sub"

basic_libraries = doc.BasicLibraries
print(basic_libraries)
print(len(basic_libraries))
for lib in basic_libraries:
    print(f'checking {lib}')
    if lib.Name == "Standard":
        print('adding macro')
        lib.createModule(macro_name, macro_code)
        break

print('here 4')
# Save the document
prop = PropertyValue()
prop.Name = "FilterName"
prop.Value = "writer_pdf_Export"
print('here 5')

doc.dispose()
```

Before running the script, I am starting scalc like this:

```
scalc.exe --accept=socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp
```

My goal is to run the python script that adds the menu instead of the popup (so if you have any idea how to replace it, I would appreciate an help!

Comment: I think the answer I am looking for involves a "OnStartApp" event but I have been unsuccessful figuring out how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The `Start Application` event can be set to run a macro by going to *Tools > Customize* and saving under "LibreOffice" in the dropdown list. This took me two tries to successfully apply and save, so it seems a bit tricky.

If you don't want to set up the event manually, according to [this post by librebel](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/struggling-to-auto-run-a-macro/30840/7), the following code will perform the setup, which you could translate to python if desired.

```
Sub connect_Start_Application_Event()
REM Call this macro once to programmatically connect the LibreOffice "Start Application" event to the Basic macro `on_ApplicationStart()`.
REM
    REM #****  Specify here the Name, Module, and Library of your Basic Macro to be called whenever LibreOffice starts:
    REM #****  This macro should be located inside your "[My Macros & Dialogs].Standard" library:
    REM #****  This macro should be defined with an Event Object as the first parameter:
    Const sMacro As String    = "on_ApplicationStart"   REM The Basic Macro to be called when the Application starts.
    Const sModule As String   = "Module1"   REM The name of the Basic Module that contains the above Macro.
    Const sLibrary As String  = "Standard"  REM The name of the Basic Library that contains the above Module.

    Dim aProps(1) As New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    aProps(0).Name      = "EventType"
    aProps(0).Value     = "Script"
    aProps(1).Name      = "Script"
    aProps(1).Value     = "vnd.sun.star.script:" & sLibrary & "." & sModule & "." & sMacro & "?language=Basic&location=application"
    
    Dim oGlobalEventBroadcaster As Object
    oGlobalEventBroadcaster = GetDefaultContext().getByName( "/singletons/com.sun.star.frame.theGlobalEventBroadcaster" )
    oGlobalEventBroadcaster.Events.replaceByName( "OnStartApp", aProps() )
    
    Msgbox "Application Event Connected: <OnStartApp> :--->  " &  sLibrary & "." & sModule & "." & sMacro
End Sub
```

However, if what you're after is a persistent menu that calls python-uno code, the normal way is to create an extension. Once installed, the menu will persist until it is uninstalled.

For example, here is part of an `Addons.xcu` file that adds a menu called "Linguistics", localized depending on the UI language of LO. In this case, the option "Phonology Settings" calls a service (technically not a macro, but it does the same things) written in python-uno that is defined in the extension.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<oor:component-data xmlns:oor="http://openoffice.org/2001/registry"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          oor:name="Addons" oor:package="org.openoffice.Office">
  <node oor:name="AddonUI">
    <node oor:name="OfficeMenuBar">
      <node oor:name="name.JimK.LinguisticTools" oor:op="replace">
        <prop oor:name="Title" oor:type="xs:string">
          <value/>
          <value xml:lang="en">Linguistics</value>
          <value xml:lang="es">Lingüística</value>
          <value xml:lang="fr">Linguistique</value>
        </prop>
        <prop oor:name="Target" oor:type="xs:string">
          <value>_self</value>
        </prop>
        <prop oor:name="ImageIdentifier" oor:type="xs:string">
          <value/>
        </prop>
        <node oor:name="Submenu">
          <node oor:name="m01" oor:op="replace">
            <prop oor:name="URL" oor:type="xs:string">
              <value>service:name.JimK.LinguisticTools.PhonologySettings?execute</value>
            </prop>
            <prop oor:name="Title" oor:type="xs:string">
              <value/>
              <value xml:lang="en">Phonology Settings</value>
              <value xml:lang="es">Configuración de fonología</value>
              <value xml:lang="fr">Configuration de phonologie</value>
            </prop>
            <prop oor:name="Target" oor:type="xs:string">
              <value>_self</value>
            </prop>
            <prop oor:name="Context" oor:type="xs:string">
              <value>com.sun.star.text.TextDocument</value>
            </prop>
          </node>
```

Even if you don't want to make an extension, using `Start Application` to continually re-create a menu probably isn't the best idea. Instead, write code to customize the menu through configuration, which will then be persistent, for example:

```
oModuleCfgMgrSupplier = createUnoService(_
    "com.sun.star.ui.ModuleUIConfigurationManagerSupplier")
oModuleCfgMgr = oModuleCfgMgrSupplier.getUIConfigurationManager( ModuleName )
oMenuBarSettings = oModuleCfgMgr.getSettings( sMenuBar, true )
```

The full code is at: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/StarBasic/Office/Favorites-Menu

Here is an example of a property value.

```
from com.sun.star.beans import PropertyValue

def createProp(name, value):
    """Creates an UNO property."""
    prop = PropertyValue()
    prop.Name = name
    prop.Value = value
    return prop

uno_args = (
    createProp("Minimized", True),
    createProp("FilterName", "Text"),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. The basic to python conversion may be an issue for me  (not sure which library PropertyValue equates to) but I will give it a shot. I'm planning on using ScriptForge instead of uno directly. I also prefer the idea of installing the menu every time so if the code changes it will automatically update the menu.

Comment: I tried to add the menu manually (as in Tools > Macros > Customize) but my (latest 7.4.5.1 x64) version does not have a Customize section of the Macros menu (see image above)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typing mistake — see edited answer.

Comment: I am feeling very foolish as I still can't see where you are suggesting to add the start macro.  I've added a snap of the customize dialog above

Comment: I've added some code that is supposed to add a popup (see above) but it is not working as noted

Comment: "where... to add the start macro" — I guess my answer doesn't explicitly say it, but it was intended to mean "Go to *Tools > Customize* and add the **event** (that is, the Events tab) called `Start Application`." But now I'm a little unclear as to whether you plan to customize to add the menu directly or to set up the event to run a script that adds the menu. (My recommendation is the first one, but it sounds like you wanted the second). Either way, it's *Tools > Customize*, but different tabs depending on what you want to do.

Comment: If "the length of basic_libraries is always zero" then you probably haven't created the Standard library yet. Do this by going to *Tools > Macros > Organize Macros > Basic > Organizer* and adding the library, or edit Basic macros, which will by default add an empty "Main" routine along with creating the library.